# How to force Vivaldi to reload page on start

Tags: browser, vivaldi

I use the new [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) browser and its Startup option is set to *Last Session*.

[image]

When I click on a restored tab, it loads it into the memory but **does not reload** the page itself, it is a *cached version* of it.

How can I force it to reload the restored page when it is loaded for display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 1.5, there is an option that can be used to *disable lazy loading*:

[image]