# How to force Vivaldi to FULLY reload page on startup

Tags: browser, browser-tabs, vivaldi

A similar question has been asked before, namely [How to force Vivaldi to reload page on start](https://superuser.com/questions/1068874/how-to-force-vivaldi-to-reload-page-on-start) - but it only concerns the *lazy loading* feature, i.e. loading a tab content only after it has been activated.
With this setting deactivated, Vivaldi will load all tabs immediately after startup. The problem is, it reads the pages from some mysterious cache instead of querying the respective addresses (i.e. fully reloading the pages). The reason I'm saying "mysterious" is because I have no idea how are the pages cached, since many of the tabs that get reloaded this fast way are wildly out of date (on the order of hours if not days).

I would like to set the browser to perform a complete reload of all the tabs - is this possible in the current release of Vivaldi?

Answer (score 4):

Since I stumbled upon this by searching for a solution to that problem: this seems to be caused by the Chromium disk cache. It worked perfectly for me for years - and then I set up my new computer and ended up with outdated pages. Both settign up a fresh Vivaldi config and moving the whole Vivaldi user settings from my old computer did not correct this behaviour. So here is what I did, in case someone needs it. 
You can either turn off disk caching completely (add the startup flag " --disk-cache-size=0" to your Vivaldi shortcut. Just change the target from e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe"
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe" --disk-cache-size=0
```

Alternatively, you can use the flags --disk-cache-dir=[path to your ramdisk] and --disk-cache-size=[size in bytes, for example 262144000 for 250MB] to point to an existing ramdisk of your choice which will be deleted on each system shutdown. I chose to use the ImDisk Toolkit for this and also freed my SSD from the Windows temp directories in that process.